# second select box is not populating data?

Tags: jquery

I have two select boxes. Based on the value selected in firstbox secondbox values are populated from mysql database. I google a lot but i didnt find the answer can anyone give me suggestion/solution.

my code:
first select box:

```
<select name="specialities" id="specialities">
<option value="select">-------select-------</option>
<option value="psychiatry">psychiatry</option>
<option value="sleep">sleep</option>
<option value="nuerology">nuerology</option>
<option value="pulmonary">pulmonary</option>
<option value="git">git</option>
<option value="general">general</option>
<option value="ent">ent</option>
<option value="cvs">cvs</option>
<option value="breast">breast</option>
<option value="reproductive_male">reproductive_male</option>
<option value="reproductive_female">reproductive_female</option>
</select>
```

this is the div where the data to be populted from db:

```
<div>
<select id="main">
  <option>----------------------------</option>
</select>
</div>
```

my jquery code for population of select box:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#specialities").change(function(){ 
     var spl = $(this).val();        
          $.ajax( 
              "doctor_details.php",
              {spl : "spl"},             
              function(data) {
                $('#main').html(data);       
             });
    </script>
```

my php page doctor_details.php:

```
$sql = "select * from doc_work_details where specalities='$_REQUEST[spl]'";

            $result = mysql_query($sql);

             while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
              {

                 echo '<option>'.$row['firstname'].'&nbsp;'.'&nbsp;'.'&nbsp;'. $row['qualification'].   '&nbsp;'.'&nbsp;'.'&nbsp;'
                  .$row['specialization'].'</option>';

              }
```

Thank you in advance
Ramsai

Comment: did you get any JS errors in console? What is the markup for second select (#main)?

Comment: just we just put the div id as main thats it

Comment: As per your PHP page, you are not putting `<select>` tag in the result string that will be put in JS `data` var in $.ajax call.

Comment: i forgot to give it i added the code of the second select box now

Comment: did you sanitize/htmlencode your values that are part of `<option>` tag ($row['firstname'] etc)? How are you packaging the `<option>` markup string so that it is available in JS function `function(data) {
                $('#main').html(data);       
             });`

Comment: here problem is first select box value is not passing to the doctor_details.php. How this to be done?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11925/discussion-between-ramsai-and-rt2800)

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert on jQuery, but in your `doctor_details.php` page, do you echo out a

```
<select> .... </select>
```

before and after the while?

Answer (score 0):

Typical way to call $.ajax() API is for example

```
 $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "Default.aspx/GetDate",
      data: "{}",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(msg) {
        // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
        $("#Result").text(msg.d);
      }
    });
```

Comment: what i have to write in msg and msg.d